# Cannot get GitLab CI to build my Middleman/Gulp project

Tags: node.js, gitlab-ci, middleman

I am using Gitlab-CI to build my Middleman application which also uses some node stuff for the front end (Gulp).

Here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` (mostly copied from [here](https://gitlab.com/pages/middleman/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml)):

```
image: ruby:2.3

cache:
  paths:
  - vendor
  - node_modules

before_script:
  - apt-get update -yqqq
  - apt-get install -y npm
  - ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
  - npm install
  - bundle install --path vendor

test:
  script:
  - bundle exec middleman build
  except:
    - master

pages:
  script:
  - bundle exec middleman build
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```

Everything goes alright apart from the vital problem that it seems to be using an old version of node when it's `npm install`ing. I'm getting lots of this:

```
npm WARN engine gulp-babel@7.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=4"} (current: {"node":"0.10.29","npm":"1.4.21"})
```

Before finally failing on the ["const path" SyntaxError](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-imagemin/issues/178).

I included a line to symlink the new nodejs with the old name (`- ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`) but it seems to have no effect...?

Been banging my head for long enough, there's got to be someone out there who has made this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian Jessie ships with a fixed NodeJs major version, [follow NodeSource instructions](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#installation-instructions) to install a specific version, this would fit in your `gitlab-ci.yml` like this (you probably need to install `curl` first since its not installed in the `ruby:2.3` image):

```
before_script:
  - apt-get update -q && apt-get -qqy install curl 
  - curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | bash -
  - apt-get update -q && apt-get -qqy install nodejs npm 
  - ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
  - npm install
  - bundle install --path vendor
```

Comment: Lovely, that's it! Worth noting there is no need for the symlink because of the more recent node install. Cheers!